# Javascript, escape is not a function - from firefox?

Tags: javascript

I'm quite puzzled by this one, getting this error from firefox.

```
escape is not a function
```

[image]
Looking at the W3C page, it says it is supported as I thought.

I tried `escapeURI` instead and this produced the same error.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Without seeing your JavaScript, I don't think we can answer the question. Does it affect *only* Firefox?

Comment: Have you declared a variable called `escape`, and if so does it have a value that is not a function? And `escapeURI` is not a native function so that won't work unless it's meant to be a function you've defined. But I'm assuming you were looking for `encodeURI`.

Comment: @JamesAllardice +1 for mind-reading :)

Comment: Incidentally, regarding `escape`, [MDN says this: "The escape and unescape functions do not work properly for non-ASCII characters and have been deprecated."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_functions).

Comment: Thanks @JamesAllardice it was declared as a variable :)

Comment: @DavidThomas this content of what is sent to escape if under control and won't receive none ascii characters, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `escape` function in DOM level 1 so your code should work. The most likely explanation for the problem is that you have either overwritten it or declared a new `escape` variable in a local scope. If the latter, then you should be able to get access to it via `window.escape`.

You shouldn't be using this function anyway; it has been deprecated because it doesn't handle non-ASCII characters very well. Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) instead.